# Use-STSRole : Credential generation from SAML authentication failed

Tags: adfs, aws-powershell

the AWS Powershell SAML code below works without problems on all windows workstations but on all windows servers we get this error:

Use-STSRole : Credential generation from SAML authentication failed.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...seSTSRoleCmdlet:UseSTSRoleCmdlet) [Use-STSRole], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.STS.UseSTSRoleCmdlet

### powershell code:

Clear-AWSCredentials

Set-DefaultAWSRegion eu-west-1

$ADFSendpoint=Set-AWSSamlEndpoint -Endpoint "https://adfs.mycompany.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx?loginToRp=urn:amazon:webservices" -StoreAs ADFSendpoint

Set-AWSSamlRoleProfile -EndpointName $ADFSendpoint -StoreAllRoles

Set-AWSCredentials -ProfileName "123456789012:role/MyRole"

$RoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyRole"

$CredentialAws = (Use-STSRole -RoleArn $RoleArn -RoleSessionName 
"MySession").Credentials

$CredentialAws

Get-S3Bucket

---

This is maddening - they are otherwise identically set up, and the ADFS endpoint still works fine in a browser on the servers, but NOT in Powershell.

This used to work recently on the servers but I am unable to find out why it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.

Fiddler revealed a certificate problem (see below) and it turned out that there was two versions of root certificate "Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority" - the version on the workstations expires 2034 and the version on the servers expires 2024 - so both should be valid, but still the 2024 version shows [chain with warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqKta.png) and the 2034 version shows [chain with no warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVXTV.jpg).

So the AWS Powershell endpoint sts.amazonaws.com must have had its certificate chain changed recently to cause this symptom.

Evt. google for Powershell script to save SSL certificate to a file for a site like sts.amazonaws.com.

-----fiddler output-----

Session #6: The server (sts.amazonaws.com) presented a certificate that did not validate, due to RemoteCertificateChainErrors.

0 - A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.

1 - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.

2 - The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.

ISSUER: CN=Amazon, OU=Server CA 1B, O=Amazon, C=US